# Ember.js Extend Model Save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, promise

I have some promise-based code (`MyLib`) that I want to run on every model save so I extend the save function:

```
DS.Model.extend
  save: ->
    parentSave = @_super.bind this, arguments...
    deferred   = Ember.RSVP.defer()

    MyLib.func().then((val) =>
      @set 'prop', val

      parentSave()
        .then(deferred.resolve)
        .fail(deferred.reject)
    )

    DS.PromiseObject.create promise: deferred.promise
```

Note that the promise returned by `MyLib.func()` is an [rsvp.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) promise and not an Ember.RSVP promise.

This seems to work in practice but some of my tests are failing with `You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run`.

Even after I wrap the `@set` and `parentSave` calls with `Ember.run`, I still have async issues in my tests.

My question is: how do I extend the save function with async code in a way that also satisfies my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The immediate error you're seeing is because all asynchronous code must run in Ember's run loop. That means that when your promise resolves and runs the `deffered.resolve` method, it must run that code inside of the run loop. So you have to do something like this:

   ```
   parentSave().then(() ->
       Em.run.next(() ->
           deferred.resolve()
       )
   )
   ```

   Hopefully that's right. Let me know if I'm missing something.
2. As of [Ember 1.5.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html), you can't call `_super` in that manner. You must call it inline and not asynchronously.